# How do I find text within curly braces that are within a string in regex (with limitations)?

Tags: regex, yaml, micro-editor

I'm trying to make a regex to find text within curly braces (and the curly braces themself) that are within double quotes, but I cannot use look-ahead, look-behind, the "^" character or the "$" character.
Also, i need to put this regex in a YAML file, but there seem to be a lot of quirks to how YAML handles escape sequences, so any help with that would be appreciated

Here is an example string for what i'm trying to find:
`"here is some {text within} curly braces"`
should find:
`{text within}`

`here are some {curly braces} outside of a string` should not find anythnig

note: I am using this for syntax highlighting with the micro text editor, which has a lot of bugs with look-ahead/look-behind, "$", and "^"

I've tried a few things, but I'm completely new to regex and the closest i got was this:
`".*({.*}).*".*`

Instead of finding the text within curly braces within a string, it would just the any line that had two curly braces that had a double quote to the left and right of this
e.g finding `"{test}"` instead of `{test}`

Comment: LIke this? `\{[^}]*\}`

Comment: That just finds the curly braces @Barmar

Comment: `[^}]*` matches the characters between the braces.

Comment: Sorry, that's what i meant
The reason that doesn't work is that it needs to find curly braces that are within double quotes
I'll edit my question to specify that by string i mean within double quotes, as i'm using this for syntax highlighting, and not data processing

Comment: Regular expressions are very poor at finding something inside something else, especially if you can't use lookarounds.

Comment: @Barmar's first response of `\{[^}]*\}` finds the curly braces plus the text between them, Wrap it in a capture group and that appears to give the text that is wanted. The comment *"That just finds the curly braces"* is plain wrong. The question is not clear. Please show some examples of what is wanted and what is not wanted, include examples with and without double quotes.

Comment: Can you use a capture group? With `"[^"]*(\{[^}]*\})[^"]*"` capture group 1 has the braced text.

Comment: What is the language--and hence regex engine--that will be used? (That should be a tag.) By "...cannot use...the "^" character or the "$" character." do you mean anchors? I've not heard of an engine that does not support anchors. As @Barmar asked, five hours ago, does the engine support capture groups?

Comment: There are different ways of storing a scalar string in YAML and only the one with double quotes and single quotes allow for escape sequences (in the single quoted one a double single quote is the escape sequence for a double one).

Plain scalars have restrictions on what they can start with and/or contain, so what you should to is use block style YAML and within that [literal scalars](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#812-literal-style): nothing needs escaping in those.

Comment: @CarySwoveland The question says this is being used within the "micro text editor" for syntax highlighting. So it's whatever engine it uses.

Answer (score 0):

Taking [`awk.yaml`](https://github.com/zyedidia/micro/blob/master/runtime/syntax/awk.yaml) as a starting point, I changed:

```
    - constant.string:
        start: "\""
        end: "\""
        skip: "\\\\."
        rules:
            - constant.specialChar: "\\\\."
```

to

```
    - constant.string:
        start: "\""
        end: "\""
        skip: "\\\\."
        rules:
            - constant.specialChar: "{.*?}"
            - constant.specialChar: "\\\\."
```